# Re-assigning something in a list not working - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to re-assign something in a list after the user has done something but it does not seem to work. Here is the culprit code:

```
table = [" "," ", " ", " ", " ", " ",]
userplay = input(": ")
if userplay == "1":
    table[1] = "X"
```

When this happens and I try to print it, it just stays the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you are using Python2.7. Use `raw_input`. Also, there is indentation issue in code within `if`. I guess you have correct indentation in actual code

Comment: You don't appear to have `table[1]  = "X"` is indented. Is that just a formatting error or is the same in the program itself?

Comment: As @MoinuddinQuadri mentioned, you need to use raw_input(). What you are getting from input is the numeric 1, which is not equal to "1" and your check doesn't work.

Comment: Which version of python are you using? Consider adding `print(repr(userplay))` to see what was typed in. Also consider adding an else clause to handle bad input.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using **Python 2**, you need either to cast your variable to string or use `raw_input()`:

```
table = [" "," ", " ", " ", " ", " ",]
userplay = str(input(": "))  # Or: userplay = raw_input(": ")
if userplay == "1":
    table[1] = "X"
```

Or even better, as mentioned by @Max, test against `int` (if you're using **Python 2** and your inputs are integers):

```
table = [" "," ", " ", " ", " ", " ",]
userplay = input(": ")
if userplay == 1:
    table[1] = "X"
```

**Note:** In **Python 3**, `input()` returns a string by default.

Comment: Or make the `"1"` a `1`. Nice solution!

Comment: @Max Disagree that the 2nd way is 'better'. Using `input` in Python 2 is like using `eval`, not recommended

Comment: @Chris_Rands I did not say the 2nd way is 'better', I said it is better to compare the input with an `int` instead of `str` if the OP's inputs are integers!

Comment: @Chris_Rands I was not implying that it was better, I was simply adding another way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

To fix your problem you can use `raw_input()` if you are using Python27.
You can find the relative doc [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input).

If you are using Python3 instead, `input()` works correctly.

I suppose that you are using Pyhton27 so the code is the following:

```
table = [" "," ", " ", " ", " ", " ",]
userplay = raw_input(": ")
if userplay == "1":
    table[1] = "X"
```

If the user insert `1`, the value of table variable is equals to

```
[' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
```